# What means the distance betwen nodes in Apache hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was reading a interview Question in Hadoop that said:

**How will you get the distance between two nodes in Apache Hadoop?**

there is a solution for that, but I don´t really understand the term distance between two nodes.

what does it means?

Comment: I assume it means network hops

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 , why should that matter? what is the advantage to know that in Hadoop?

Comment: Because Hadoop is a distributed system and a larger cluster means more network switches to go across... Like I said, it's an assumption, otherwise the question doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good answer: https://qr.ae/pGRAyl

You can find more implementation details here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.10.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop HDFS is a distributed system and a larger cluster means more network switches.

when you are reading files throw HDFS , First, you request name node to get information about file blocks' locations. These blocks are distributed over different machines.

if at some point a datanode you retrieve data from died you get this data from another replica without bothering users about it.  you will get data from the closest machine. The meaning of closeness, in reality, is difficult to measure. Because it depends on the physical distance and unpredictable system load such as metric overutilization. For this reason, it's on data center topology.

thats why its important to know the distance between nodes in Hadoop